# Add column to worksheet in last position with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl to automate some operations on an Excel file. Right now I'm trying to add a new column (which would be "S") in a worksheet with dimensions A1:R56.
What I tried is:

```
ws=wb[sheet]
last_column=ws.max_column
ws.insert_cols(last_column+1)
```

But the dimensions of the worksheet and its number of columns don't change. I use insert_cols(last_column+1) because the function would add a new column before the given index, so I add +1 thinking it would add the new column after the last one and not before it. Clearly I'm doing it wrong. Could you help me please?

Comment: You're inserting an empty column to the **right** of the last column, ie where there is already an empty column.

Comment: @CharlieClark I checked but there are no columns to the right of the last column. Neither before or after using insert_cols(last_column+1). The dimensions of the worksheet and number of columns don't change.

Answer (score 0):

You're approach seems correct, curios ,if you are saving the file by calling the save_wb() Method.

I created something similar (with additional part, where I take user input for column name as well). Please see, if this is useful for your scenario

```
# Method to add a new column with name as the last column of active worksheet
# Arguments to this method are: - New column name and row number of header row
def add_new_col_at_the_end_to_active_ws(self, _header_row_num, _new_col_name):
    # New column will be added only if, it does not exist already
    if _new_col_name not in self.get_col_names_active_ws(_header_row_num):
        # Note:- Since we are adding the column at the end, we need to auto identify its index
        # We are using the existing max_column property of the worksheet and incrementing it by 1
        _new_col_idx = self.my_base_active_ws_max_col + 1
        # Once the columns is added, we correctly identify the cell where the column name will be written
        self.my_base_active_ws.cell(row=_header_row_num, column=_new_col_idx).value = _new_col_name
        # This method calls save internally, hence its auto save from user perspective
        self.save_wb()
```